When commit is pushed to main, re-run github actions on feature-branch
I have a PR that branches off of main:

Whenever a commit is pushed to main or feature-a, I would like to run github actions on feature-a.
AKA:

Is there a github actions trigger for this?

Read through the github action doc, but haven't found any solutions to this yet.

Trigger on push, filter to branches: main, and then checkout with feature-a?

When your workflow is triggered on the main branch, you could trigger the same workflow on a feature branch:
name: trigger-main-to-branch

on:
  push:
    branches: '**'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref_name == github.event.repository.default_branch
    steps:
      - name: Build main
        run: echo Build main branch
      - name: Trigger feature branch build
        run: |
          echo Trigger feature branch build
          gh workflow run --ref feature-a trigger-main-to-branch
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  feature:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref_name != github.event.repository.default_branch
    steps:
      - name: Build feature branch
        run: echo Build feature branch

I am using GitHub CLI gh which is available on GitHub runners. It requires an environment variable GH_TOKEN that has permissions to trigger workflows. Default Github token has this permission.
